# Asynchronous Email Plugin Domain Classes

Tags: email, grails, asynchronous

Experimenting with Asynchronous Mail 0.2.1 using Oracle as backing database.  Running small test app and logSql=true shows that plugin is trying to create a table called asynchronous_mail_message_headers which Oracle can't do (only <= 30 characters allowed in identifiers).  I've looked for where this domain is being created but I can only see two domains in the grails-app/domain/ru/perm/kefir/asynchronousmail directory of the plugin (neither of which are this particular domain).  There are also other tables being created I can't account for looking at the available plugin code.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a join table being implicitly created.  If the domain classes have a many/many or unidirectional one/many relationship it's possible.  You may need to tweak this table creation using the joinTable directive in the relevant domain class.

[joinTable docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html)

Comment: Thank you - that was it.  There a was a Map<String, String> headers that I modified headers -> hdrs which makes the join table 30 and works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks aquatoad for the push.  Custom join table created by mapping in ru.perm.kefir.asynchronousmail.AsynchronousMailMessage:

```
headers joinTable:[name:'asynch_mail_message_headers',key:'asynchronous_mail_message_id']
```

Comment: Thanks... if you could accept the answer so it doesn't appear on the "unanswered questions" list that'd be great :)  Glad I was able to help.